# New user: Cannot post question because it looks like spam

Tags: support

I can't seem to post it anywhere in order to link it, so I took a screenshot. The question (though wordy) is this:

"What does current research show regarding the use of sunscreen as a preventative measure against skin cancer in people with deeper skin tones?"

This was posted in the Medical Sciences SE. I'm a new user and had just created my account, so perhaps there's a waiting time before allowing me to post.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you [edit] to give us the *exact* rejection message? It seems (although I can't see from the image where the links actually go) to be OK as a question. Spam-filters usually kick-in *after* posting rather than before. Since the system allowed you to make an account, presumably your IP address hasn't been blanket-banned. Hopefully someone'll come along with some idea of what's going wrong there. Oh, and welcome to Stackexchange :)

Comment: @W.O. Thanks for helping me out and the welcome. I edited the question with the error message. It mentions that I need to resolve an error, but I see nothing anywhere on the page that's highlighted so that I can correct it. Only that error message pops up with nothing else.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Did you add a question title in the dedicated box? - Also, is there no more specific message than that? Just to note, there's a 30,000 character max, can you check how near you are? (At rough estimation, you're nowhere near).

Comment: @W.O. Yeah, the quote at the top of my post is what I have in my question box. It's within the character limit. The body is at 2540 characters. I see no other indication of an error.

Edit: "This looks like spam" seems to be the only other thing that lets me know anything. But that's it.

Comment: Nor do I. There is a network-wide posting throttle for new users, but since you've no other questions save this one, I'm stumped. You've not had any questions deleted on medical have you?

Comment: @W.O. No, this is my first account and that is my first question. I think there's a contact to SE suggested by Sonic, so I'll see if that leads anywhere. Thanks for your help and suggestions :)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'll message them and see if they're aware of what's going on.

Comment: @W.O. "*Since the system allowed you to make an account, presumably your IP address hasn't been blanket-banned.*" everyone is always allowed to make an account regardless of the IP ban. It's not rare that spammers recreate their accounts soon after getting nuked.

Comment: As for this issue, you might want to try posting the question without any links first. If it's successful, then edit and add the links one by one.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. This fixed it. Guess it either didn't like my citations or just didn't want me posting links with a new account, which is fair. Thanks.